# docker dead but pidfile exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I was working on docker on AWS instance and it was working fine. On one day, docker stopped working. When i restarted docker "service docker start", it started and "service docker status" returned "docker dead but pidfile exists" message and docker commands did not executed. When i inspected log file, it showed following messages:

```
msg="+job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)"
msg="Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)"
msg="There are no more loopback devices available."
msg="loopback mounting failed"
```

To start docker, i removed pid file from /var/run/docker.pid, /var/run/docker.sock and also removed docker from /var/lock/subsys/docker and restarted docker. But no gain. It still gives same error on start "docker dead but pidfile exists".

Please help.

Comment: Any reply experts???

Answer (score 0):

This ticket could be related with the loopback issue.

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7058

So, please check output from `losetup -l` and `ls -l /dev/loop*`

**EDIT**: If `ls -l /dev/loop*` returns an error, most likely cause is the github ticket I indicated, and then you would need something like

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..6}
do
    mknod -m0660 /dev/loop$i b 7 $i
done
```

(taken from the mentioned issue)

Also, if you only want to restart, you may need to `umount` `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper` or any mounted volume of type `aufs`

Comment: "losetup -l" returned nothing. ls -l /dev/loop* gives: "ls: cannot access /dev/loop*: No such file or directory" and "umount /var/lib/docker/devicemapper" gives: "umount: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper: not mounted
" So i am still at where i started.